# Dart How to calculate mean?

Tags: dart

How to calculate the mean of an non-empty list of double in Dart ?

The math [library](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-math/dart-math-library.html) does not have mean method hence:

```
math.mean(mylist) // does not work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the mean by dividing the sum by the length. As long as you know the list is non-empty the sum can be calculated with a `reduce` call.

```
var mean = numbers.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / numbers.length;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Just call `.average`**

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; 

void main() {
  final list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  final sum = list.average;
  print(sum); // prints 2.5
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting but I can't seem to find this package?

Comment: My bad, I added a wrong import. I updated the answer now